# how to download many pdf files from google at once using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, google-api

I want to download approximately 50 pdf files from the Internet using a python script. Can Google APIs help me anyhow?

Comment: I would look at `asyncio` and `aiohttp` modules. These are built for doing heavily concurrent stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume that you are downloading from Google drive.  You can only download one file at a time.   You cant batch download of the actual file itself.

YOu could look into some kind of multi threading system and download the files at the same time that way but you man run into quota issues.